# Second order linear differential equation where $\lambda$1 and 2 is same number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation 
$$y''-4y'+4y=0 $$
$$y(0)=0 $$
$$y'(0)=1$$

I get $ r_1=2, r_2=2$
That means i have the general solution

$$ Ce^{2x}+De^{2x}$$
where C and D are arbitrary constants

Solving with initial constant 
 $$ y(0)= Ce^{0}+De^{0}=C+D=0 $$
 $$ y'(0)= C2e^{2x}+D2e^{2x}=2C+2D=1 $$
which gives
 $$ D=1/2-C$$
But when i insert D into the first initial constant
$$ C+1/2-C=0 --> 0=1/2 $$

That does not make sense. It seems to me i got the general solution somehow wrong. Is there a special case for when $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the same number?

Comment: The general solution is $Ce^{2x}+Dxe^{2x}$

Comment: That means the case for one real $\lambda$ is used? Why? I have two real $\lambda$s?

Comment: Aren't your "two" real lambdas the same number?

Comment: @Artem yes, so that means i just have one right? I get your point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s suppose that $r$ is a root of multiplicity $k$ (i.e. $r$ occurs $k$ times in the list of roots).  We will then get the following $k$ solutions to the differential equation,
$$
e^{rx},\;xe^{rx},\;\ldots,\;x^{k-1}e^{rx}
$$
So, for repeated roots we just add in a t for each of the solutions past the first one until we have a total of $k$ solutions.

In your case $r=2$ has multiplicity $k=2$, so that
$$\begin{align}
y(x)&=ae^{2x}+bxe^{2x}\\
y'(x)&=2ae^{2x}+be^{2x}+2bxe^{2x}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in the initial conditions gives the following system:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
y(0)&=0=a\\
y'(0)&=1=2a+b\Rightarrow b=1
\end{align}\right.
$$
The actual solution to the IVP is then
$$
y(x)=xe^{2x}.
$$